# Explain lazy Pascal's triangle in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I came across this elegant implementation of Pascal's triangle that uses a lazy sequence.

```clojure
(def pascal
  (iterate
   (fn [prev-row]
     (->>
      (concat [[(first prev-row)]] (partition 2 1 prev-row) [[(last prev-row)]])
      (map (partial apply +) ,,,)))
   [1M]))
```

Could anyone help me understanding the `,,,` in this context? I tried using `macroexpand` but that didn't get me far. I also know it's use is not required, but I want to know that `,,,` means.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Commas are treated as white space in Clojure so Reader will ignore `,,,` completely. The reason it is there is to make the code more readable for humans.

In this context, the `->>` macro will insert the `(concat ...)` in the last position of the call to `(map ...)`, i.e. in the position of `,,,`.

The `,,,` commonly used with `->` and `->>` macros  to make the code more readable, but does not actually do anything.